# Different connection speed to URL depending on number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, url, urlconnection

I need your advice. I'm trying to make some sort of code that will bulk check av. connection speed to URLs in multiple threads. Code works. But I don't understand why when I'm using 4 threads the av.connection speed  is say 150ms and using 20 threads it can raise up to 500-600ms ? Any clues?

The idea of how the code below should work: In main I start a "ThreadManager" that starts multiple Threads that will establish connections with URLs. URLs are kept in a synchronized ArrayList, and the results are also written in a synchronized ArrayList.

```
package URLConnectionSpeedChecker; 
public class ThreadManager implements Runnable{

private static Base base;

@Override
public void run() {
    base = new Base();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        CheckerThread checkerThread = new CheckerThread(base);
        Thread thread = new Thread(checkerThread);
        threads[i] = thread;
    }
    for (Thread x : threads) {
        x.start();
    }
    for (Thread x : threads) {
        try {
            x.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static Base getBase (){
    return base;
}
```

The code that is run in a thread:

```
package URLConnectionSpeedChecker;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckerThread implements Runnable {

private static Base base;

CheckerThread(Base base) {
    this.base = base;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (base.getIsOutlistOfURLs() == false) {

        long timeDifference = 0;

        try {
            timeDifference = connectTime(base.getListOfUrls());
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        addTimeDifference(base.getListOfTimeDifferences(), timeDifference);
    }
}


public long connectTime(ArrayList<String> list) throws IOException {
    long startTime = 0;
    long finishTime = 0;
    long timeDifference;

    URL url = getURL(list);
    if (!(url == null)) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.connect();
        finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeDifference = finishTime - startTime;
        return timeDifference;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

synchronized public void addTimeDifference(ArrayList<Long> list, long timeDifference) {
    list.add(timeDifference);
}

synchronized public URL getURL(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {

        if (list.get(0).length() > 0) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(list.get(0));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.remove(0);
            return url;
        } else if (list.get(0).length() < 0) {
            list.remove(0);
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        base.setIsOutlistOfURLs();
        return null;
    }
}
}


}
```

Comment: I assume the most time consuming call is the urlConnection.connect, and that the JVM executes thread change when waiting for the connection. If there are 20 threads sharing the same timeslots I also would expect that the connect operation in average lasts 5 times longer than with 4 threads. Nothing special.

Comment: @Heri thanks! I guess I got it!